# Filebeat multiline patter

Tags: docker, logstash, filebeat

I would like to configure a multiline pattern for each docker container that are deployed. I know that I can configure different filebeat inputs but the thing is that I don't know which container I am using because the path of the container log is like /var/lib/docker/containers/{id}/[{id}.log

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob-patterns in your filebeat configuration:

a setting like this

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
```

Should match any file you'd be looking for?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#input-paths

Please make sure that a file is not being matched by multiple path-settings.

***Edit below as per added requirements.***

So for example you would have these 2 containers running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
77e87b8e772e        yadayada                                   "/hihihi"                 2 weeks ago        Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:9080->9080/tcp   container1
99e87b8e772e        blablabla                                  "/hahaha"                 2 weeks ago        Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:9080->9080/tcp   container2
```

based on the provided information, the assumption is then that:

container1 logs in `/var/lib/docker/containers/77e87b8e772e/77e87b8e772e.log`
container2 logs in `/var/lib/docker/containers/99e87b8e772e/99e87b8e772e.log`

This might be the config:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths: /var/lib/docker/containers/${CONTAINERID1}/${CONTAINERID1}.log
  multiline.pattern: '^=[A-Z]+|^$'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
- type: log
  paths: /var/lib/docker/containers/${CONTAINERID2}/${CONTAINERID2}.log
  multiline.pattern: '^=[1-9]+|^$'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
```

So when starting filebeat, you do some additional things before actually running filebeat:

```
export CONTAINERID1=$(docker ps|grep "container1$" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
export CONTAINERID2=$(docker ps|grep "container2$" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
./filebeat
```

This way, as long and the container name remains the same, the ID can be different and will still work. Please note though that when you spin up a new (version of a) 
container, you will have to restart Filebeat to pick up the new path.

Also please note that if you run Filebeat in a docker container itself, exporting the variable will most likely not be enough, you will have to edit the file using
`sed` or something before you pass it into the filebeat-container

Comment: I want to analyze all the docker containers but each one could have a different multiline pattern. /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log is the one that I am using...

Comment: Ah okay, that changes things. Perhaps you could update your initial post to "a different multiline pattern for each docker container"?

That being said, you could utilize environment variables in the config at startup?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.2/using-environ-vars.html

Use `docker ps | grep something` to fill the variables before executing filebeat and use those variables in the config.

Comment: I am not really sure how an env var would help me to configure a different multiline pattern...the only way I see is to configure different inputs type for each id container...but I don't want to do it with ids because I do not know the connection between id and container name...

Comment: Besides multiline option is configured for filebeat input section not for each type..

Comment: As for the relation between id and name: that's what the grep is for. I'll update my initial answer.